# How to check if there is any read/write activity for a specific harddrive with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I'm curious how to assess if there is any read- or write-activity for a specific harddrive at a given moment with .NET / C#. Second it would be interesting to assess the actual speed of access.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the [Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa310909(VS.71).aspx) APIs which are supported in the .NET Framework via the [System.Management and System.Management.Instrumentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720682(VS.71).aspx) namespaces.